# Collapse a DIV to zero height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK, what I need should be very simple but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work :

- I've got a block (`<div id="searchArea" class="collapse in"></div>`) which I'm trying to collapse/show
- I'm using the following Bootstrap-compliant code :

  ```
  <div class="row" style="margin-left:20px;">
        <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchArea">SEARCH</button>
  </div>
  ```

**Now, here's what :**

- How could I start with the block collapsed at startup?
- (Most important) Why does the supposedly "hidden" block, when collapsed, still maintains some height? (e.g. it does collapse but not to zero, it's still perfectly visible). How could this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > How could I start with the block collapsed at startup?

   Remove `.in` from your `#searchArea` to have `<div id="searchArea"
   class="collapse"></div>`
2. > Why does the supposedly "hidden" block, when collapsed, still maintains some height? (e.g. it does collapse but not to zero, it's
   >   still perfectly visible)

   Apparently the block you want to have collapsed has padding assigned and that's what gives
   you the visual placeholder when the block is collapsed. You should either remove paddings from the block or you could try using `box-sizing: border-box` on your `#searchArea`.

Comment: That's what I call "great answer" and "to the point". You can't imagine how much time of head-to-wall-contact you've saved me. lol. (And yep, there *was* some padding in that block...). Thanks A LOT! :-)

Comment: SO's imposed delays between posting and accepting answers... Thanks again! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

if you give us some code in here, it would be usefull but try;

```
display : none;
```

instead of

```
display : hidden;
```

and you can do this onload attribute in body unless you don't use jquery

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery use [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/). It will slide your `div` up and `display:none;`

Comment: I'm basically using Bootstrap's Collapse component (yep, it should be based on jQuery) : http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse